# "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tinymce is not a function " error on JQuery ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

Hi there I try load [tinyMce](https://www.tinymce.com) plugin with jQuery load ajax.

I try this:

index.php

```
<body>
<div id="editor"></div>
<div id="button"></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
function check()
{
    tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
}

$("#button").click(function(){$("#editor").load("editor.php", function() 
{
    $.getScript('//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js', function() {
        check();
    });
});
});
</script >
</body>
```

Also in editor.php

```
 <textarea></textarea>
```

But I got this error on console:

> VM1647:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tinymce is not a function

how can handle these error?

Comment: Seems that you need to load the `tinymce.min.js` after loading JQuery library..!

Comment: Mostly it happens due to not loading the required js library file on time.!

Comment: I thought  getScript do that! So how can I load 'tinymce.min.js'

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for what you want to accomplish :

**Tested Myself:**

**index.php :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
var url = "http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
  $( "#go" ).click(function() {
    $( "#editor" )
      .load("editor.php");
  });
});
</script>

<button id="go">Load</button>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

**editor.php :**

```
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
```

Comment: because it's a  part of big forms and I want load it with ajax (if user needs it)...I want smaller html size for index.php